# Pandas: Combine two dataframe with the samse structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I'm using python 2.7 and I have two dataframes like this:

```
df1

| index |  colA   |  colB  | colC |
-----------------------------------
|   1   |    A    |  None  |   X  |
|   2   |   None  |  None  |   D  |
|   3   |    B    |   C    | None |

df2

| index |  colA   |  colB  | colC |
-----------------------------------
|   1   |   None  |  None  | None |
|   2   |    Y    |   Z    | None |
|   3   |   None  |   None | None |
```

My objective is to combine them in one dataframe containing a minimum of None values.
both dataframes have same index.

```
df3

| index |  colA   |  colB  | colC |
-----------------------------------
|   1   |    A    |  None  |   X  |
|   2   |    Y    |   Z    |   D  |
|   3   |    B    |   C    | None |
```

Comment: It seems dupe, need `df = df1.combine_first(df2)` or `df = df1.fillna(df2)`

Comment: do you know the difference between combine_first, fillna and update ?

Comment: Nort easy answering, maybe you can create question for it.

Comment: Ok i will do it .